# Trouble installing MySQL from binaries

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, mysql

So, I am a freshman in Computer Science, and I have dug an old computer out of my garage to use as a personal hosting server for various services (email, web site, subversion, etc.), partly because I actually need those things and partially for the learning experience.

WOPR (props if you get the reference) is a 10yr+ old Dell Dimension with 256 MB RAM and a 500MHz Intel Pentium III processor. It is running Arch Linux 2010.05 (kernel 2.6.33); I downloaded the MySQL binaries [from here](http://www.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.15-linux2.6-i686.tar.gz/from/http://mysql.he.net/) just now and tried installing.

I am following this procedure from the MySQL docs:

```
    shell> groupadd mysql
    shell> useradd -r -g mysql mysql
    shell> cd /usr/local
    shell> tar zxvf /path/to/mysql-VERSION-OS.tar.gz
    shell> ln -s full-path-to-mysql-VERSION-OS mysql
    shell> cd mysql
    shell> chown -R mysql .
    shell> chgrp -R mysql .
    shell> scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
    shell> chown -R root .
    shell> chown -R mysql data
    shell> cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
    shell> bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
    shell> cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server
```

I get the following messages:

> ```
> WARNING: The host 'WOPR' could not be looked up with resolveip.
> This probably means that your libc libraries are not 100 %
> ```
>
> compatible
>       with this binary MySQL version. The MySQL daemon, mysqld, should
>   work
>       normally with the exception that host name resolving will not
>   work.
>       This means that you should use IP addresses instead of hostnames
>       when specifying MySQL privileges !
>       Installing MySQL system tables...
>       ./bin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> ```
> Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
> ./data for more information.
>
> You can try to start the mysqld daemon with:
>
>     shell> ./bin/mysqld --skip-grant &
>
> and use the command line tool ./bin/mysql
> to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:
>
>     shell> ./bin/mysql -u root mysql
>     mysql> show tables
>
> Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using --log
> gives you a log in ./data that may be helpful.
>
> Please consult the MySQL manual section
> 'Problems running mysql_install_db', and the manual section that
> describes problems on your OS.  Another information source are the
> MySQL email archives available at http://lists.mysql.com/.
>
> Please check all of the above before mailing us!  And remember, if
> you do mail us, you MUST use the ./bin/mysqlbug script!
> ```

I have glibc installed from the latest version of Arch. Does anyone know what libaio.so.1 is, what package it comes from, and what its dependencies might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install libaio from AUR:

```
aurbuild -s libaio
```

Comment: I don't have AUR, but I found a binary and installed; that took care of it. Thanks so much!